# Matplotlib: Stacked Bar Graphs

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using [matplotlib's stacked bar graph example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) with a couple of issues. Can you please help me understand why my code is not stacking the values appropriately?

```
N = 3
#('PledMis', 'PledFel', 'FoundFel')
Incarceration   = (115.3, 1.99,23.7 )   
Probation   = (52.0, 45.9, 45.0)   
Work   = (0, 0.3, 2.4)   
Program   = (0, 0, 12)   

ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.5           # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

p1 = plt.bar(ind, Incarceration, width, color='r')
p2 = plt.bar(ind, Probation, width, color='y',bottom=Incarceration)
p3 = plt.bar(ind, Work, width, color='b',bottom= Probation)
p4 = plt.bar(ind, Program, width, color='g',bottom=Work)

plt.ylabel('Months')
plt.title('Time')

plt.xticks(ind+width/2, ('Found Guilty: Felony', 'Pled Guilty: Mis', 'Pled Guilty: Felony' ) )
plt.yticks(np.arange(10,200,10))
plt.legend ((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0], p4[0]), ('Incarceration', 'Probation','Work','Program' ))

plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*you do not take the other data points into account for `bottom`.
try this:

```
import numpy as np
N = 3
#('PledMis', 'PledFel', 'FoundFel')
Incarceration   = np.array([115.3, 1.99,23.7] )   
Probation   = np.array([52.0, 45.9, 45.0])   
Work   = np.array([0, 0.3, 2.4])   
Program   = np.array([0, 0, 12])   

ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.5           # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence
p1 = plt.bar(ind, Incarceration, width, color='r')
p2 = plt.bar(ind, Probation, width, color='y',bottom=Incarceration)
p3 = plt.bar(ind, Work, width, color='b',bottom= Probation+Incarceration)
p4 = plt.bar(ind, Program, width, color='g',bottom=Work+Probation+Incarceration)
```

if you do multiple bar plots and want to stack them, it might be more sufficient to use a loop and accumulate the bottom with an own variable:

```
colors = ('r', 'y', 'b', 'g')
data = (Incarceration, Probation, Work, Program)
bottom = np.zeros(N)
for elem, color in zip(data, colors):
    plt.bar(ind, elem, width, bottom=bottom, color=color)
    bottom += elem
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes perfect sense :)

Comment: You you re-write this to use a loop to accumulate the bottom variable (rather than writing out the addition in each step)?  Maybe (at the danger of self-promotion on my part) include a link to https://gist.github.com/tacaswell/b1a35a27a7d73f7408d2